# WIx "Remember property pattern" not allowing properties to be available in custom action

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.9

I am using Wix version 3.9R2

I followed the suggestions [here](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/) to create persistable properties across installs/repairs/uninstalls of my product.

When I am installing, the properties set from the command-line get sent correctly to my custom action method. When I re install the product they do not, although the log shows that the properties are populated with the correct values. Here are my [install logs](https://gist.github.com/theonlylawislove/83f37d5c4f5b8334d3a0) (both install and repair).

Also, here is my wxs file. I omitted some parts that I don't think were relevant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix>
  <Product>

    <!--These are all of our properties that we can configure-->
    <Property Id="APPPOOLUSERACCOUNTTYPE" Value="networkService" />
    <Property Id="APPPOOLUSERNAME" Value="Username" />
    <Property Id="APPPOOLUSERPASSWORD" Value="Password" />
    <Property Id="DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING">
      <RegistrySearch Id="DatabaseConnectionStringProperty" Root="HKLM"
                      Key="SOFTWARE\MedXStorage\Database"
                      Name="ConnectionString" Type="raw" />
    </Property>
    <Property Id="DATABASENAME">
      <RegistrySearch Id="DatabaseNameProperty" Root="HKLM"
                      Key="SOFTWARE\MedXStorage\Database"
                      Name="DatabaseName" Type="raw" />
    </Property>

    <!--Actions to restore any settings set from the command line-->
    <CustomAction Id="DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING_SaveCmdLineValue" Property="CMDLINE_DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING" Value="[DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING]" Execute="firstSequence" />
    <CustomAction Id="DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING_SetFromCmdLineValue" Property="DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING" Value="[CMDLINE_DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING]" Execute="firstSequence" />
    <CustomAction Id="DATABASENAME_SaveCmdLineValue" Property="CMDLINE_DATABASENAME" Value="[DATABASENAME]" Execute="firstSequence" />
    <CustomAction Id="DATABASENAME_SetFromCmdLineValue" Property="DATABASENAME" Value="[CMDLINE_DATABASENAME]" Execute="firstSequence" />

    <!--Action that deploys the database-->
    <CustomAction Id="DeployDatabaseAction"
               BinaryKey="MedXStorage.InstallerActions.dll"
               DllEntry="DeployDatabase" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <!--Restore and settings set from the command line-->
      <Custom Action="DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING_SaveCmdLineValue" Before="AppSearch" />
      <Custom Action="DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING_SetFromCmdLineValue" After="AppSearch">CMDLINE_DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING</Custom>
      <Custom Action="DATABASENAME_SaveCmdLineValue" Before="AppSearch" />
      <Custom Action="DATABASENAME_SetFromCmdLineValue" After="AppSearch">CMDLINE_DATABASENAME</Custom>
      <!--Lets try to deploy our datbase-->
      <Custom Action="DeployDatabaseAction" After="InstallInitialize">
        <![CDATA[&DatabaseFeature=3 OR REINSTALL><DatabaseFeature]]>
      </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <InstallUISequence>
      <!--Restore and settings set from the command line-->
      <Custom Action="DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING_SaveCmdLineValue" Before="AppSearch" />
      <Custom Action="DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING_SetFromCmdLineValue" After="AppSearch">CMDLINE_DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING</Custom>
      <Custom Action="DATABASENAME_SaveCmdLineValue" Before="AppSearch" />
      <Custom Action="DATABASENAME_SetFromCmdLineValue" After="AppSearch">CMDLINE_DATABASENAME</Custom>
    </InstallUISequence>

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Here is my C# action method.

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult DeployDatabase(Session session)
{
    try
    {
        session.Log("Begin DeployDatabase");

        var connectionString = session["DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING"];
        var databaseName = session["DATABASENAME"];
        var dacpacLocation = session["DATABASEDACPACLOCATION"];

        session.Log("Starting database deploy with...");
        session.Log("   ConnectionString=" + connectionString);
        session.Log("   DatabaseName=" + databaseName);
        session.Log("   DacpacLocation=" + dacpacLocation);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            session.Log("Connection string must be provided.");
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            session.Log("Database name must be provided.");
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dacpacLocation))
        {
            session.Log("Dacpac must be provided.");
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }

        if (!File.Exists(dacpacLocation))
        {
            session.Log("The dacpac doesn't exist at " + dacpacLocation + ".");
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }

        SqlPackage.Deploy(dacpacLocation, connectionString, databaseName, (messageType, message) => session.Log("Sql deploy message: " + messageType + ": " + message));

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        session.Log("Error deploying database.");
        var exception = ex;
        while (exception != null)
        {
            session.Log("---");
            session.Log("Message:" + exception.Message);
            session.Log("Stacktrace:" + exception.StackTrace);
            session.Log("---");
            exception = exception.InnerException;
        }
        return ActionResult.Failure;
    }
}
```

In the repair logs, you can see it setting the properties correctly.

```
Property(C): DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING = Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False
```

However, in my custom action, I can't retrieve this property.

```
Starting database deploy with...
   ConnectionString=
   DatabaseName=
   DacpacLocation=C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA791.tmp
```

Why does this same msi give me the correct properties values during install, but none on repair?

Comment: Properties should be marked Secure=:yes" if they are to be transferred from the UI sequence into the server's execution sequence - that might be the issue.

Comment: @PhilDW, that was it! Why not post an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Chris has the same answer, so good thing it's correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WiX uses the Secure attribute on the Property element to build the [SecureCustomProperties property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371571(v=vs.85).aspx).

> The SecureCustomProperties is a list of public properties delimited by
>   semi-colons. These properties are included with the default list of
>   restricted public properties that the installer can pass to the server
>   side when doing a managed installation with elevated privileges.

FWIW, the remember me property pattern is incomplete in my opinion.  I usually take it a bit farther to implement a property source precedence pattern also.  The idea is that a value passed at the command line or selected in the UI should override the remembered value which should override the default value.

Comment: Do you have a write-up on your "property source precedence" pattern somewhere? I've been searching the web and looking through your blog and haven't found anything.

Comment: I've posted it a few times but don't know where.  Ask a new question and I'll answer it.

Answer (score 3):

Properties should be marked Secure=:yes" if they are to be transferred from the UI sequence into the server's execution sequence - that might be the issue.